# created a assignment rule on lead. But no queue is assigned.

Tags: assignment-rules, queue

I have created a assignment rule on lead. When a lead is created get assign to a user x. I have not added the user to the Queue. Even then the lead is getting assign to the user x. when the lead is created. Then what is the role of queue object in this process. Or how to use the queue in this process. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is checkbox in the bottom of page named "Assign using active assignment rule". You must check it if you want assigment rule to apply to this record

Comment: yes, I checked it and it is getting assigned to the person defined in assignment rule. I just want to know what is the use of Queue object in this process.

Comment: basically queue is collection of records with defined list of users who share owner rights to this records. So if you want to have team of people working with leads you should create queue and make this queue owner of those leads.

Comment: thanks @Artur, but when we assign the which user should be the owner of lead with criteria, the how we are using Queue with Assignment rule. If possible can you please give me an example.